# {margins}, {indentation}, and changing the "margins" in the middle of a page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Perusing [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) and [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation), I've noticed that these two tags in fact cover at least *three* concepts:

1. Changing the (top/bottom/left/right) margin(s) for a whole document or at least for a whole page. This is the rightful domain of [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins), often accompanied by the [geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) and/or [typearea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typearea) (package) tags.
2. Switching on/off first-line indentation for all or specific paragraphs. This is covered by [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation). (I'm not aware of any package-specific tags, though the `indentfirst` package would fit in.)
3. Changing the (left/right) "margins" in the middle of a page, e.g. for [lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists), [quoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) environments, and [theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theorems). Questions concerning this matter feature either [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) or [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation) or both tags, with no discernible pattern.

I think we should come to an understanding to which tag questions of the third type belong -- [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins), [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation) or even a yet-to-be created new tag. I suggest that [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation) is in fact the appropriate tag, and ask you to advance your opinion.

(Note: From the 30 highest-scoring [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) questions, 4 belong to the "middle-of-the-page" type. Assuming about the same fraction for the whole tag, adoption of my proposal would mean the necessity to retag about 20 to 30 questions. It is possible that Stefan Kottwitz, owner of the sole [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/136/margins) tag badge, would lose this badge at least temporarily. Assuming that at least 100 [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) question would remain, the tag badge would not be destroyed, but "orphaned" the same way as it happened for the [memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoir) badge.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my proposal has gained 4 upvotes, I will begin to retag the " middle-of-the page" type questions from [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) to [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation). I suggest the following wiki excerpt for [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins):

> {margins} is about changing the margins of (whole) pages and,
>   conversely, the width and height of the textblock and its positioning
>   on the page. Popular packages are {geometry} and {typearea}. For
>   changing the "margins" in the middle of a page, use {indentation} 
>   instead.

Note, however, that tex.sx features *exactly* 40 tags with more than 200 questions right now and [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) is likely to fall below this mark. This in turn may affect the process of awarding "Generalist" badges. Because of this, retagging will only be completed as soon as another tag (possibly [installing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing), [amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsmath), or [footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footnotes)) exceeds 200 questions.